# How to get the number of result from a v-if?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is probably a stupid question, but i am searching how to get the number of result from my v-if which is in a v-for ?

My code:

```html
<div v-for="conv in conversation.hits" :key="conv._id">        
   <div v-if="conv._source.status == false">
      <b-badge variant="info">Nouveau message</b-badge>
   </div>    
</div>
```

And I want to replace my text by the number of the result after my conditions if, it is possible?

Thnks,

Comment: Can you paste the data in `conversation` array? Also, it's not exactly clear what do you mean by `result` from `v-if` directive here.

Comment: Actually i got 2 conversations which have status false so i print two times <b-badge variant="info">Nouveau message</b-badge>, and i just want to get the number of the result.
No it's complicated :>

Comment: Okay, so basically you want to get the number of conversations with `status==false` and print in the badge, correct?

Comment: Yeah exactly, i got the number after my v-for with lenght but after my v-if idk how to do

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not really clear from the question why you looping over the conversations and printing the lengths, but if you want to find the length of items that satisfy a certain criteria you can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then print it's length.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="withStatusFalse(conversation.hits)">
      <span variant="info">{{ withStatusFalse(conversation.hits) }}</span>
    </div>
    <div v-if="withStatusTrue(conversation.hits)">
      <span variant="info">{{ withStatusTrue(conversation.hits) }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoList",
  data() {
    return {
      conversation: {
        _id: 1,
        hits: [
          { _source: { status: false } },
          { _source: { status: false } },
          { _source: { status: false } },
          { _source: { status: true } }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    withStatusFalse(converstationHits) {
      return converstationHits.filter(el => !el._source.status).length;
    },
    withStatusTrue(converstationHits) {
      return converstationHits.filter(el => el._source.status).length;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**P.S**: I have created `withStatusFalse` & `withStatusTrue` as `methods` instead of `computed` properties so that you don't have create multiple `computed` properties in case you wish to filter out multiple arrays based on the same condition. If you're going to have just a single array called `conversation.hits` in your code, then you can use `computed` properties instead like below:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="withStatusFalse">
      <span variant="info">{{ withStatusFalse }}</span>
    </div>
    <div v-if="withStatusTrue">
      <span variant="info">{{ withStatusTrue }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TodoList",
  data() {
    return {
      conversation: {
        _id: 1,
        hits: [
          { _source: { status: false } },
          { _source: { status: false } },
          { _source: { status: false } },
          { _source: { status: true } }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    withStatusFalse() {
      return this.conversation.hits.filter(el => !el._source.status).length;
    },
    withStatusTrue() {
      return this.conversation.hits.filter(el => el._source.status).length;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Let me know if you need the `v-for` for any specific reason, I'll update the answer along with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to implement your solution.

I prefer to keep the template logic as simple as possible so I created a computed property `falseHits` to filter the conversation hits. The result is cached and reactive to changes in `conversation`. See [Vue Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) and [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="conv in falseHits" :key="conv._id">
      <span>Nouveau message</span>
      {{ falseHits.length }}
      {{ conversation.hits.length }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      conversation: {
        _id: 42,
        hits: [
          { _id: 1, _source: { status: false } },
          { _id: 2, _source: { status: true } },
          { _id: 4, _source: { status: false } },
          { _id: 3, _source: { status: true } },
          { _id: 5, _source: { status: true } }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    falseHits () {
      return this.conversation.hits.filter(hit => !hit._source.status)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```